# In PostgresQL, how do I make a query match exactly one row or fail?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am making an arbitrary DELETE or SELECT query and I know this should effect or return only one row. How can I ensure that the query doesn't execute and I get some signal that something is wrong when more then one row matches?

Using LIMIT and ORDERBY allows the operation to continue, rather than doing a hard abort. Meaning multiple objects may be subject to DELETE with no chance to recover.

Preferably whatever signal results would be distinct from having zero match.

Comment: You may try to use your query in a subselect in a select clause. As a subquery in a select clause should be scalar, it will raise an error if you get more than one row (or more than one column)...

Or you may control use a PL/SQL function/procedure and raise an error if you get more than one row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Arkhena, use a scalar subquery to determine the row to access:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
            FROM MyTable
            WHERE ...whatever ...);
```

If the subquery returns more than one ID, the query fails.
This requires some unique key (here: ID).

---

If you do not want to get an error from the query, you can use CTE for the filter, and then check the number of rows in the CTE:

```
WITH r AS (
  SELECT ID
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE ...whatever...
)
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM r) = 1
  AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM r)
RETURNING ID;
```

This statement will return an ID value only if one row was actually deleted.